# Android ExpandableListView garbled on orientation change when background color not set

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've found what I think is a bug in the ExpandableListView.

I have an ExpandablelListView implemented in a fragment called from an action bar tab.  If I change screen orientation from portrait to landscape and back to portrait the display becomes garbled (the previous view of the list is displayed statically as well as the new view).  If I make exactly one change - to set the background color of the expandablelistview the problem goes away and the list redraws correctly on screen orientation change.

Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Regards,

Dean

Comment: Which API version do you use? Have you tried this on a emulator or on a real device?

Comment: Hi - android:targetSdkVersion="17" - only tested on devices.  Three separate ones - a Nexus S, a Nexus 4, and a Galaxy Tab 10.1.